# How to display variable type when hovering in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, ide, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 in C#. When hovering over a variable when the program is not running, a pop-up appears showing the variable type and name. However, when the program is running and hits a break-point, hovering only shows the name and value, but not the type. I would like it to display the type when the program is running as well.

For example, say I have the following code:

```
var foo = 100;
```

When the program is stopped and I hover over the variable `foo`, it displays `(local variable) int foo`. However, if I set a break-point right after that line, run the program, and then hover over it after hitting the break-point, it displays `foo | 100`. Is there a way to get it to show something like `int foo | 100`?

I've tried searching online and looked through the options provided in Tools > Options > Debugging, but I didn't find anything that looked like what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get it to show something like int foo | 100?

I'm afraid the answer is negative. The option which displays `(local variable) int foo` and that(DataTips) which displays `foo | 100` are two different things.

VS use [DataTips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/view-data-values-in-data-tips-in-the-code-editor?view=vs-2019#work-with-datatips) option to show the quick info during debug mode.
For this option,it displays **quick info** about the variable when you hover over it, which doesn't support detailed type message like what you want: `int foo | 100`.

I recommend you use [watch window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2019#observe-variables-with-a-watch-window) to observe the value and type of variables.Select the variable you want, right-click and choose `add watch` to observe it. Or drag it to watch window when debugging to watch it.

Also, you can open a [locals window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows?view=vs-2019#use-the-autos-and-locals-windows) to watch variables with type message in current scope.

Comment: That's a bummer. It'd be really convenient to just hover over a variable in break mode to see its type. But at least having the Locals window open should be helpful. Thanks for the tips. 